# first Occurrence Of Non Blank Cell vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write VBA code which works on my Excel sheet.

Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row  gives me the row number of the last non blank cell. similarly i am trying to get the row number of the first non blank cell in that particular column.
Thanks in advance.
madhu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same function, just check to see if the first row is blank.

```
Dim firstRow as Integer

If ActiveSheet.Range("A1").value = "" Then
    firstRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Else
    firstRow = 1
End If
```

If the first row is not blank and you use the `End(xlDown)` call you won't get the first non-empty cell you will get the last non-empty cell before the first blank cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the IsEmpty(cell) function, which returns a boolean true/false.

Comment: For using `IsEmpty` it has to loop through cells whereas the accepted answer does not need any and its more efficent.